# Updating a d3.js Angular directive with new chart data results in an infinite digest?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, infinite-loop

I've got a d3.js chart directive in Angular which needs to stay up to date with the latest data provided. What appears to be happening is that Angular is throwing an `infinite digest` error (why?) when new data is sent from my server, and I can't figure out why.

#### directive

```
(function() {
    var app = angular.module('app');

    app.directive('chart', ["$window", function($window) {
        return {
            replace: true,
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                data: '=',
                settings: "="
            },
            link: function($scope, elem, attrs) {

                $scope.$watch('data', function(newValue) {
                    render(newValue);
                }, true);

                function render(data) {
                    // complex d3 manipulation here
                }

            },
            templateUrl: '/js/templates/chart.html'
        }
    }]);
})();
```

#### directive HTML binding

```
<chart class="dataplot" data="telemetryPlots.altitudeVsTime.data" settings="telemetryPlots.altitudeVsTime.settings" width="100%" height="400px"></chart>
```

#### parent controller

```
(function() {
    var app = angular.module('app', []);

    app.controller('myController', ["$scope", "myService", "telemetryPlotCreator", function($scope, myService, telemetryPlotCreator) {

        (function() {
            missionService.telemetry($scope.slug).then(function(response) {
                $scope.telemetryPlots = {
                    altitudeVsTime: telemetryPlotCreator.altitudeVsTime(response.data)
                }
            });

        })();
    }]);

    app.service('telemetryPlotCreator', [function() {
        this.altitudeVsTime = function(telemetryCollection) {
            return {
                data: telemetryCollection.filter(function(telemetry) {
                    return telemetry.altitude != null;
                }).map(function(telemetry) {
                    return { timestamp: telemetry.timestamp, altitude: telemetry.altitude };
                }),
                settings: {
                    extrapolate: true,
                    xAxisKey: 'timestamp',
                    xAxisTitle: 'Time (T+s)',
                    yAxisKey: 'altitude',
                    yAxisTitle: 'Altitude (km)',
                    chartTitle: 'Altitude vs. Time',
                    yAxisFormatter: function(d) {
                        return d / 1000;
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    }]);

    app.service('myService', ["$http", function($http) {
        // http service
    }]);
})();
```

I'm not seeing my mistake here, as far as I can tell there's nothing that should be retriggering a digest apart from when necessary. What mistake am I making?

Comment: Is it because the watch is being called a multiple number of times..can you check that how many times its getting called.

Comment: Removing the watch removes the infinite digest... but then I have no way of updating the chart data.

Second request, I don't know how to do that.

Comment: can you check on the console the oldvalue and newvalue $watch('data', function(newValue, oldValue) more over you are doing a deep watch by setting 3rd parameter to true hope you have done it for a purpose..

Comment: I don't see anything that would cause an infinite digest in this code on first glance. But you should provide the contents of the `render` function. If that function is changing `data` at all, that will trigger an infinite digest.

Comment: can you comment your render() call in the watch and check, 
if the render call is changing any property in 'data' , it would call the watch again, and probably infinitely which can cause the infinite digest issue